# Как правильно обособить вводное слово в предложении со вставкой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, вставная-конструкция, вставка

*"Чего я, кстати — при всей моей солидарности с коллегами, — не делаю".*

В этом предложении, как мне кажется, запятая должна стоять не перед первым тире, а перед вторым, так как вставка не относится к вводному слову "кстати". Правильно ли я рассуждаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что запятую следует поставить всё же перед первым тире:

*Чего я, кстати, — при всей моей солидарности с коллегами — не делаю.*

> **4.** В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо **тире**, могут быть еще **запятые**. Здесь возможны следующие случаи:
> <...>
> 2) перед первым **тире** ставится **запятая**, если этого требует структура первой части основного предложения: *Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — **какой ужас!** — и руки бессильно опустились у него* — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения.

А можно вообще перед каждым тире поставить запятые, сославшись на это:

> Следует, впрочем, заметить, что часто встречается своеобразная «симметрия» знаков (постановка запятой перед вторым тире, если перед первым тире стоит запятая).

Источник: [Вводные и вставные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123) (справочник Розенталя).